# How object can be stored as reference in array, list or map?

Tags: c++

Lets take an example of array

```
class Bird{
public:
int a;
};

void fn(Bird& obj){
Bird& arrayList[5];
arrayList[0] = obj;
arrayList[0].a = 10;
}
```

Here any update in arrayList will not  be reflected in obj object 
My requirement is to stop copying obj object. arraylist should refer obj ;

Pls don't use array of pointer to Bird

Comment: You need to explain why you want to do this (the example is silly - why have an array when you only ever access the first element). It is probably not possible as you have phrased the question, because a reference can only be initialised, not assigned (assignment assignes to the referred object, not the reference).

Comment: Pointers are designed exactly for this purpose. Of course when using raw pointers (like `Bird*`) your object owning policy must make sure that objects (you keep pointers to) exist. If you need shared ownership then you need smart pointers of some kind (like `boost::shared_ptr<Bird>`). What is the reason of not using pointers?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have an array of references.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: I wanted to add that too but OP doesn't want to use array of pointers, `Pls don't use array of pointer to Bird`, So I was a bit lost as to what to advice? :)

Comment: my advice is to use an array of pointers. If the OP doesn't want to use an array of pointers, then he will not be able to achieve what he wants, period.

Comment: @Alex: He could use an array of `boost::ref` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard is quite clear about this (see 8.3.2 and 8.3.4). In a nutshell, an array is a sequence of *objects*. A reference is *not* an object. Hence, you cannot have an array of references.

(For similar reasons, there are no references to references or pointers to references: references are aliases for *objects*, and pointers point to *objects*, but references are *not* objects themselves.)

Answer (score 0):

The construction you used:

```
Bird& arrayList[5];
```

Is not allowed. You should store the objects themselves:

```
vector<Bird> Birds;
Bird arrayList[5];
```

or the pointers

```
vector<Bird*> Birds;
Bird* arrayList;
```

These are the only recommended options.

Comment: So why exactly *doesn't* a reference work? (Trying to flush out a slightly more thorough reply or links.)

Comment: @pst: I think FredOverflow's answer will clear up your question